# Receiving UDP packets from gateway / hotspot

Tags: linux, networking, udp, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi setup as a WiFi hotspot (it is a DHCP server and it has HOSTAPD running). It does not have an internet connection and isn't routing traffic. Clients only connect to its network when they want to communicate with it.

I have a python script on the Raspberry Pi that is sending a UDP message ~5 seconds.

I can see the packets being sent through Wireshark (which I have installed on the Raspberry Pi), but none of the clients that connect to the Pi's network can see those packets. It's like they are hitting a dead end somewhere before they get out of the Pi.

I should also mention the clients have their firewalls turned off.

Here's some screenshots from the Pi:
You can see Wireshark shows the packets being sent. You can also see BROADCAST is enabled on wlan0.
[image]

The client (a Windows 10 computer in this case) is also running Wireshark and you can see the network info for it too:
[image]

What am I missing in the network setup that is keeping this broadcast from reaching clients? If I connect the Raspberry Pi to a real router, the clients on that network can see the UDP messages fine. That makes me think there is something wrong with the self-hosted hostspot I setup.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

The contents of the hostapd config:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
#driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=PI032378
channel=6
dtim_period=1
beacon_int=400
```

Here's the Wireshark info about the packets that are being sent, but not received:

```
Frame 162: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (wlan0)
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Feb 21, 2017 16:45:08.000647000 Central Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1487717108.000647000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.007711000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 1.299469000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 162
    Frame Length: 60 bytes (480 bits)
    Capture Length: 60 bytes (480 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: Shenzhen_0c:b4:25 (40:a5:ef:0c:b4:25), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Destination: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    Source: Shenzhen_0c:b4:25 (40:a5:ef:0c:b4:25)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.42.1, Dst: 192.168.42.255
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 46
    Identification: 0xa04d (41037)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xc420 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 192.168.42.1
    Destination: 192.168.42.255
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 44661, Dst Port: 5003
    Source Port: 44661
    Destination Port: 5003
    Length: 26
    Checksum: 0x779c [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    [Stream index: 3]
Data (18 bytes)
    Data: 426c756562657272793a5049303332333738
    [Length: 18]
```

Comment: Googling finds [similar issues](http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2014-March/029760.html) with broadcasts using hostapd on a RaspPi. Might be a driver/hostapd issue.

Comment: @dirkt thanks for the link. I modified my hostapd.conf with the dtim_period and beacon_int. I also turned off power_save mode and none of that helped. The Pi can receive UDP broadcasts from the network clients, but the clients cannot receive UDP broadcasts from it.

Comment: Can you post your hostapd config file?

Comment: @Spiff I added it to the question. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Can you ping the Windows machine from the Pi?

Comment: @JasonWilliams are the other devices connected to any other network or just Pi?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes, the Pi can ping the Windows machine and the Windows machine can ping the PI.

Comment: @nafas no, the clients are only connected to the Pi.

Comment: Have you tried unicast on the same port, instead of broadcast?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes, I have been able to send unicast messages to a specific IP address.

Comment: So most likely the broadcast packet is dropped inside your Windows machine. It would be important to have a non-Window machine to confirm that the problem is on that machine. Also, sorry for asking the obvious: are you sure you placed the wifi card in **promiscuous** mode on Windows? It  *might* happen that the broadcast packet is discarded inside the NIC, after all it is the only thing that precedes Wireshark.

Comment: @JasonWilliams are you trying to broadcast? if so what IP and port are you using to broadcast?

Comment: @JasonWilliams Set ur broadcast ip to e.g. 230.0.0.10  and make clients to listen to this ip  (NOTE this is a reserved IP for broadcasting)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I wrote a small Android app that receives the UDP packets and it does not work when directly connected to the PI's network. It does work when both are connected to the same router. I don't think it's a Windows-specific problem.

Comment: @nafas Currently, the server (Raspberry Pi) is broadcasting to it's subnet's broadcast address (192.168.42.255 in this case). I will try to switch to the address you suggested (230.0.0.10). I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @nafas The message I get when trying to send to that broadcast address is "network is unreachable."

Comment: @JasonWilliams, hmm, interesting. I just did a dummy server is broadcasting to address 230.0.0.10 (port 10101)  and clients read from that address (port 10101). and it worked. Here is more info on it :
http://www.vsicam.com/_faq/what-is-the-difference-between-unicast-and-multicast-streams/

Comment: @JasonWilliams I used this little example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html  (note there is a typo for IP used :203.0.113.0 it should be like 230.0.0.10)

Comment: @JasonWilliams alright mate, try this one, server sending data to 192.168.42.255 and client request data from 230.0.0.1 (ensure its multicast stream I know in java you can specify this) also  please make sure ports are the same for both client and server :D

Comment: @nafas Thanks for the ideas, but that's not working either. Broadcasting to 192.168.42.255 and having the clients listen on 230.0.0.1, 230.0.0.10, 192.168.42.255, or 255.255.255.255 doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54019/discussion-between-nafas-and-jason-williams).

Comment: Can you just post the **whole** broadcast packet which the RPI sends, and is not received by the Windows and Android machines?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I've added packet info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Multicasts and broadcasts on 802.11 must be sent using a modulation scheme (data rate) that every client can receive. They must be one of the rates in the Basic Rate Set (mandatory rate set) for that network, and they must be encrypted with the group key and group cipher for that network.

Although you might have a multicast rate problem, if you're using encryption (i.e. WPA2-PSK), it's more likely to be an encryption problem. As a test, try turning off wireless encryption in your hostapd config and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The network is currently "Open" with no password or encryption and the problem is occurring.

Comment: @JasonWilliams Can you do an 802.11 Monitor Mode capture? Are the broadcasts getting on the air? Maybe the broadcasts are getting transmitted into the air, but the client devices aren't receiving them successfully. What data rate (modulation scheme) is the RPi using when transmitting these broadcasts? It would also be helpful to see a decoded beacon so I can see what capabilities the RPi is advertising.

Comment: I know some of those things :)
It's apparently hard to get a monitor mode capture on Windows (the only client I have laying around right now).
As far as the beacon, do you have a suggestion about how to capture that? I've got an app called "WiFi Analyzer" that shows some detail, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the WiFi Analyzer / beacon information: [link](http://imgur.com/UbIbOrO)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the network interface on the Raspberry Pi is calculating the UDP checksums incorrectly. You can check if the checksumming is offloaded to the network interface by running `ethtool -k eth0` (or`ethtool -k wlan0`, or whatever the network interface you are serving the DHCP server on) on the Raspberry Pi. If its output shows that the checksumming is on (i.e. `tx-checksumming: on`), you can try to disable checksumming:

```
sudo ethtool --offload eth0 tx off
```

I've had this issue, and there's a [relevant question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93731/raspberry-pi-dhcp-server-clients-not-getting-ip-addresses) on the Raspberry Pi stackexchange.